# ggplot - how can I show percentage proportions and total sum

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization

My code:

```
  ggplot(data=data,aes(x=month,y=as.numeric(properties),fill=show)) + 
  theme_light() + 
  geom_col(alpha=.8) +
        geom_text(aes(label=round(..y../1000,1),group = c(show)),
        position=position_stack(vjust=.5),vjust=-.2,size=2) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1,size=6),
              legend.position = "bottom",
              axis.title = element_text(size = 8),
              axis.title.y.left = element_text(size = 10)) +
  ylab("Properties") + xlab("Month") +
  scale_fill_manual("Show", values = c("YES" = '#b3b3b3', "NO" = '#8080ff'))
```

My plot:
[image]

Example data:

```
month   show properties
-------------------
2017-05 NO  2.1     
2017-05 YES 4.1     
2017-06 NO  2.1     
2017-06 YES 4.2
...
```

How can I change sum of each group to percentage proportions and how can I add total unit sum over each bar at the same time?

Comment: please include some data using `dput(data)` for instance.

Comment: I just added example data to description

Comment: "properties" seems to be missing from the columns?

Comment: @brtk showing sample data in a table is not ideal because we cannot paste it easily into IDEs and it lacks type information. Please use ```dput(data)``` as suggested. If that is too much data (or confidential) use ``` head(data) %>% dput()```.

Comment: I corrected properties

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. So for the percentage, you need to add another column with the calculated percentage and use that as label in geom_text(). For the sum, you need to calculate it separately and introduce it as a geom_text() with a separate data frame:

```
# convert to numeric at the start
data <- data %>% mutate(properties=as.numeric(properties))
# calculate percentage
data <- data %>% group_by(month) %>% mutate(perc=round(100*properties/sum(properties),1))
# make another data frame with sum
sumdata <- data %>% group_by(month) %>% summarize(properties=sum(properties))

# almost the same plot with 
g = ggplot(data=data,aes(x=month,y=properties,fill=show)) + 
  theme_light() + 
  geom_col(alpha=.8) +
        geom_text(aes(label=perc,group = c(show)),
        position=position_stack(vjust=.5),vjust=-.2,size=2) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1,size=6),
              legend.position = "bottom",
              axis.title = element_text(size = 8),
              axis.title.y.left = element_text(size = 10)) +
  ylab("Properties") + xlab("Month") +
  scale_fill_manual("Show", values = c("YES" = '#b3b3b3', "NO" = '#8080ff'))+
 geom_text(data=sumdata,aes(x=month,y=properties+0.15,label=properties),
inherit.aes=FALSE,size=2)
```

[image]